# shell iteration while skipping nodes

Tags: shell, for-loop

I have 20 nodes out of which 5 does not ssh(this is expected).
These values are dynamically pulled from a source.
Below is my code trying to check if they are able to SSH:

```
for skip_node in "${skip_nodes[@]}"
do 
    for node in "${nodes[@]}"
    do

        if [[  $node != $skip_node ]]; then continue; fi

        <I have my ssh logic working here>
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
            UNABLE_TO_SSH+=" ${node}"
            (( ERROR_COUNT += 1 ))
        fi
    done
done
```

This script is failing because array nodes again contains those nodes which are in skip_nodes.
Any help on how should can I solve this problem?

Comment: Not sure why you have continue in your code. It's probably that that is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have succeeded in achieving this.
I have substracted 2 lists and then iterated over the final list for SSH check.

```
nodes=($(comm -3 <(printf "%s\n" "${nodes[@]}" | sort) <(printf "%s\n" "${skip_nodes[@]}" | sort) | sort -n))
for node in "${nodes[@]}"
do
    <my code for checking ssh>
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        UNABLE_TO_SSH+=" ${node}"
        (( ERROR_COUNT += 1 ))
    fi
done
```

Comment: Why use an indexed array rather than an associative array in the first place here?